# What comes next in the series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, puzzle

Well, here is a numerical sequence puzzle, which I really tried hard, but still could not find the pattern? 
2
4
6
30
32
34
36
40
42
44
46
50
52
54
56
60
62
64
66
x?

Can anybody help me out in finding the pattern in these numbers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the integer sequences [A006933](https://oeis.org/A006933), describing  Sloane's Eban numbers, $2, 4, 6, 30, 32, 34, 36, 40, 42, 44, 46, 50, 52, 54, 56, 60, 62, 64, 66, 2000, 2002, 2004, 2006$, $2030, 2032, 2034, 2036, 2040, 2042, 2044, 2046, 2050, 2052, 2054, 2056, 2060, 2062, 2064$, $2066, 4000, 4002, 4004, 4006, 4030, 4032, 4034, 4036, 4040, 4042, 4044, 4046, 4050, ...$

More information is [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EbanNumber.html).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, without any further assumptions, there's no way of telling what is next. What is next in $0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18$? 
Maybe it is $20$ [A005843](https://oeis.org/A005843) or maybe $11$ [A062028](https://oeis.org/A062028)? Or maybe something entirely different?

Infinitely many sequences are in accordance with any given starting values, so deciding which one is "correct" assumes that we severely restrict search space to, for instance, "common" sequences. (I don't know why above $20$ should be more correct than $11$, but I'm sure almost everyone will say $20$ is next, not $11$).